# Compare meta_query decimals not working right

Tags: custom-field, wp-query, meta-query

I have a custom field named 'rating' that holds decimals from 1.0 to 10. I am trying use wp_query to get me all the posts with a rating of 8.0 to 10. What I have so far almost works perfectly but it does not return posts with rating of 10.

```
<?php add_filter('get_meta_sql','cast_decimal_precision');
    function cast_decimal_precision( $array ) {
    $array['where'] = str_replace('DECIMAL','DECIMAL(1,1)',$array['where']);
    return $array;}
?> 
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
    'category_name' => ( 'movies' ),
    'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'rating',
                    'value' => 8,
                    'compare' => '>'
                )
                ),
    'meta_key' => 'rating',         
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args); 
?>
```

Comment: What happens if you set `'type' => 'NUMERIC'` on your `meta_query`?

Comment: When I did that none of the posts for ratings in 8 showed up. Only 9, 9.5 and 10. So 10 did show up but not in the right order and again left out all of the 8's.

Comment: Well yea, you used an exclusive comparator. Is 8 greater than 8?  I think not. 8 is equal to 8...so you want your comparator to be `>=`. I'll go ahead and submit this as a solution.

Comment: Oops. You are right. But the 10's are now showing up at the end. I have a order DESC so they should be at the top. Any way to fix that as well?

Comment: See the solution I just submitted, if that's still an issue post a comment on the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the default comparison for `meta_query` is a `CHAR` comparison, so the order that the numbers would be in by default would be 1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, a, etc. To resolve this you need to modify your `meta_query` as follows:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'rating',
        'value'   => 8,
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
    )
),
```

Comment: The 10's are still showing up at the end of the list rather than at the top.

Comment: That's because `meta_value` is a `CHAR` ordering system. `meta_value_num` is a `NUMERIC` ordering system. Read the [documentation for `WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) before you ask for further clarification please.